# How can i delay shutdown until virtualbox closed

Tags: c#

I try to shutdown vbox before local shutdown/restart/logoff etc.
i try something but dont work.
My code is:

```
private void VMStarter_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    ...
    ShutDownHandle.StopShutdown(this.Handle, "Virtual Box is shutting down...");
}

private void tmr_doWork_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tmr_doWork.Enabled = false;
    Controller.closeVM();    //for
    while (!ShutDownHandle.ResetShutdown(this.Handle))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
    ShutDownHandle.Shutdown();
    this.Close();
}

//[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (!systemShutdown)
        if (m.Msg == (int)EnumClass.WindowsMessageCodes.SM_SHUTTINGDOWN ||
            m.Msg == (int)EnumClass.WindowsMessageCodes.WM_ENDSESSION ||
            m.Msg == (int)EnumClass.WindowsMessageCodes.WM_QUERYENDSESSION)
        {
            tmr_Check.Enabled = false;
            //Message MyMsg = new Message();
            //MyMsg.Msg = (int)EnumClass.WindowsMessageCodes.WM_CANCELMODE;
            //base.WndProc(ref MyMsg);
            systemShutdown = true;
            tmr_doWork.Enabled = true;
            return;
        }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

ShutDownHandle class: include StopShutdown and ResetShutdown methode. I use `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` and `ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy` to stop closing window.

```
public static bool StopShutdown(IntPtr hWdn, string strMessage)
{
    try
    {
        if (ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(hWdn, strMessage))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Writer.errorWrite(ex);
    }
    return false;
}

public static bool ResetShutdown(IntPtr hWdn)
{
    try
    {
        return ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(hWdn);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
        Writer.errorWrite(ex);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I click shutdown while app is running and get this

[image: error]  [image: error]

How can i do? what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try this
in your method tmr_doWork_tick
put async like this

async void tmr_doWork_Tick(object sender, etc..)
{

// here is your thread.sleep();
 //  reemplace for await Task.delay(10);

}

Comment: I have a .bat file for shutdown VirtualMachine. It must run. But it doesn't until click cancel button that appears in the picture. When i click cancel, usually run and Virtual Machine shutdown. Any idea for this situation.